# how to give the chance to update or rename the treelist node at the time of inserting?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtratreelist

I'm using xtratreelist control from the DevExpress. I'm creating child node when user clicks on the parent node. And that time it adds the default named child node. But i want to show the cursor at the newly inserted child node for editing the child nodes text.

```
private void addNewGroupToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 TreeListNode childNode = treeList1.AppendNode(new object[] { "My Group" + DateTime.Now }, 1);
 treeList1.FocusedNode = childNode;
 treeList1.ShowEditor();
 treeList1.ExpandAll();
}
```

I've implemented same functionality in the treeview control. By using treeview's LabelEdit property & treeView's AfterLabelEdit() method. But i'm getting these property & method in the treelist control.

whether is it possiblem? If yes then suggest some information depending on this.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you are using the TreeList's AppendNode method to create a new node.  If so, this method returns a new TreeList node  object.  So, to be able to edit this node value, you should:

1) focus this node;

2) open the editor;

This can be done using the following code:

```
TreeListNode node = treeList.AppendNode(..);
treeList.FocusedNode = node;
treeList.ExpandAll();
treeList.ShowEditor();
```

**UPDATE**: I've modified the code and it works properly.  The problem was caused by the ExpandAll method which closes the editor...

Comment: @Richa, I though that this code would work.  Could you be so kind and explain what is wrong?

Comment: @DevExpress Team i used this code in my addingnode menu strip's click event. and when i click on the menu that time it add's child node with my default name. but it not showing any editor for editing the childnode name. I edit my question & add same code what i'm using.  If i'm wrong then please tell me where i'm wrong.

Comment: @DevExpress Team i've changed my code but it is still not working. Is it because of the default name of the node which i've given when the child node is being created?

Comment: @DevExpress Team i got my answer i changed the treelist's `OptionsBehavior.Editable = false` for my application purpose & i set this property equal to `true` before Showeditor() method. But i'm having one trouble that after completing editing i've to call `CloseEditor()` method , but i don't know where to call this method. The treeview provides `AfterLabelEdit()` event. But i don't know which event should i use. Can u help me?

Comment: @Richa, The TreeList will close the editor itself.  It is necessary to focus another node, or press the Enter (to commit), Esc(to cancel) changes.  So, it is up to you to decide when the editor should be closed.